# CSS Transition on pseudo element did not work on Safari

Tags: hyperlink, webkit, css-transitions

I try to create on hover hyperlink animation. When user hover on the link it will animate the underline. 
I put the code here : http://codepen.io/elaelation/pen/bkicn

It works very well on Chrome & Firefox, but it did not work on Safari. I already put the `-webkit-transition` for Safari bug, but it still didn't work.
Is there anything wrong with my code ?

thank you.

Comment: I just found a good article here : http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/
CSS transition on pseudo element is not supported yet in Safari. You can read the detail on the article above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a good article here : http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/
CSS transition on pseudo element is not supported yet in Safari. You can read the detail on the article above.