# CSS Sliding Underline does not work in Safari?

Tags: css, safari, hover

I have created a navigation menu which has a 'sliding underline' effect for each hyperlink.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZuQR/12/

RELEVANT CODE:

```
/* sliding underline */

    nav li a:after {
        content: " ";
        display:block;
        margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
        border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
        width: 0px;
        transition: 0.5s ease;
        }

        nav li a:hover:after {
            border-bottom: 3px solid #0076a3;
            width:50px;
            }
```

This solution works in Chrome **but not in Safari**. Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transition of pseudo elements are not yet supported by Safari. Here:

[CSS Transition on pseudo element did not work on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920827/css-transition-on-pseudo-element-did-not-work-on-safari)

and here:

http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/

Comment: Hmm that's interesting, I did not realise this was the case. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the sake of keep things updated, Safari 6.1+ now supports it ;D